# AS3 listen for start of mp3 playback

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio

Is it possible to listen for when a streaming mp3 actually begins to play?

e.g.

```
var snd:Sound = new Sound();
snd.load(new URLRequest("my.mp3"));
snd.play();
```

When loading/streaming the mp3 file over wifi or 3G the playback might not begin immediately.

I need to trigger something when the audio actually starts.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a complete event for the Sound object that will fire when the data has loaded successfully. Assuming that the audio starts playing immediately after the loading is complete you can make use of this event.

Another approach would be use to the SoundChannel object returned by Sound.play and keep polling the position attribute of the SoundChannel object. The position attribute has a value greater than 0 then the audio has started.

Comment: Thanks Srisa. Polling the bytesLoaded value of Progress Event did the trick. private function progressHandler(e:ProgressEvent):void {
 trace(e.bytesLoaded);
 if (e.bytesLoaded > 20000) {

Answer (score 1):

```
...
snd.load(new URLRequest("my.mp3"));
snd.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);

function loaded(event:Event):void
{
   // here play
}
```

Comment: Do you know if this gets triggered when ALL data has been downloaded or when the first bytes are loaded?

Comment: As far as I kwow, when ALL data has been loaded. Please, if you must choose an answer, choose the Srisa's one.

Comment: Agreed! ProgressEvent was the key.